# Json response from retrofit+jackson convertor

Tags: android, jackson, retrofit

I want to know if it is possible to access the response body as a string when having success response. Here i get the success :

```
   serviceOne.editionsGet(Device, new Callback<Editions>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Editions editions, Response response) {
               //here i get my results
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                showErrorToast();
            }
        });
```

I suppose it can be in body response in the body . If it is how to get from it the string body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
InputStream is = response.getBody().in();

BufferedReader br = null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line;
try {

    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (br != null) {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

String body = sb.toString()
```

Comment: using the code above i used Google Guava v11.0 and the next code
 InputStream is = null; try {is = response.getBody().in();} 
catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }  try {
String text = CharStreams.toString(CharStreams.newReaderSupplier((InputSupplier<? extends InputStream>) is, Charsets.UTF_8));
                } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
  try {is.close();} catch (IOException e) {                e.printStackTrace(); }
It gives me the next error ClassCastException:java.io.ByteArrayInputStream cannot be cast to com.google.common.io.InputSupplier

Comment: Oops. Thought you could cast using Guava. Updating answer to just use a standard bufferedreader.

Answer (score 0):

It should be accessible with `response.getBody().toString()`.

`editions` should be the Object returned by retrofit, which you implement yourself

`response` should be the response body returned by retrofit, which contains the body and can be accessed as String by using `getBody().toString()` method.

Comment: TypedByteArray[length=287494] that is result of response.getBody().toString() , but i need the json as string

Answer (score 0):

Well using JSONNode you can get json in response

```
  ApiInterface apiService =
            ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<JsonNode> call = apiService.setDevice("application/json","eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdXRoX3Rva2VuIjoiMjY5NTUzNzIyOSIsImxvZ2luX2lkIjoiUlY1OTk3In0.NnPNRVUgaQnRBiza9yXM8FJf069Hb2ROtFw2mdlqK3w",rawJsonData());

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonNode>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonNode>call, Response<JsonNode > response) {
            Log.e("MAIN",response.body().toString());
          /*  Model model=response.body();
            model.getstatus();*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonNode>call, Throwable t) {

            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.e("MAIN", t.toString());

        }
    });
```

just use this

```
 @POST("device")
Call<JsonNode> setDevice(@Header("Content-Type") String content_type, @Body Device parm);
```